# Enable/disable text box in Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to disable the textbox when the checkbox is checked in a user control (ACSX page). These controls are in a gridview.

```html
<div>
  <asp:GridView ID="gvModifOuvrageNonControles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="MarionGridView">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO CONTROL">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInspection" OnClick="grisé(this);" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RAISON">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCause" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

```js
function grisé(obj) {
  alert(obj.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this grid has 3 columns i.e 2 Template field and one BoundField cause it will be needed while grabing the textbox..

[image]

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvModifOuvrageNonControles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO CONTROL">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInspection" OnClick="grisé(this);" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RAISON">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCause" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <script>
            //all disabled at first..
            (function () {
                debugger;
               var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%=gvModifOuvrageNonControles.ClientID %>");
                for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {
                    var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells[2];
                    cell.firstElementChild.disabled = true
                }
            })();


            function grisé(obj) {
                debugger;
                var rowData = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
                if (obj.checked) {
                    rowData.cells[2].firstElementChild.disabled = false
                }
                else {
                    rowData.cells[2].firstElementChild.disabled = true;
                }
            }

        </script>
    </form>
</body>

   --------------- code behind ----------------
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            r["ID"] = i;
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        gvModifOuvrageNonControles.DataSource = dt;
        gvModifOuvrageNonControles.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Tay ! Thank you for your answer ! I just made a mistake, I want the textbox to be disable when the checkbox is not checked ! Can you help me with that. And also if a user remove a the check i want the text box to be enabled again..(thank you so much)

Comment: It help ! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Not a problem !!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must do is set the PostBack property of the checkbox to true.

Then you have to iterate through the gridview's item template and find the checkbox using the FindControl method.

Once the checkbox control is found you will need to create an event handler for the checkbox and when it is checked,and, again using the FindControl method, find the textbox within the gridview and perform your action.

This is done in the code behind for your user control. It's a cleaner approach, rather than trying to write a huge script for just one action.

Please note that I am not at my PC so I can't provide an example for the code.